# Att dsl modem changing my router's dns?

Tags: router

I have a DSL modem provided to me by ATT yahoo DSL.  Its a weston brand connected to a linksys router with 4 ethernet ports and wireless.
I have the linksys router set to a specified DNS 192.168.0.21 which is a windows machine. every so often the ip address for the DNS on the router changes to 192.168.1.254 which is the gateway ip address for the ATT modem.

Any ideas what might be causing this?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If your router is set to static IP configuration on the outside interface then it can't (or atleast shouldn't) change.

If it's set to DHCP on the outside interface then it'll get new DNS servers every time the lease renews from your ISP.

Comment: I did a major rewrite here to make it a bit better - A hint for the OP: The TCP/IP protocol does not allow you to have different DNS servers for a specific interface (unless you use some weird nat/masq rules)